# Слова утворені від прізвищ в українській мові

Tags: етимологія, власні-назви

Наприклад, в англійській мові слово *бойкот* з'явилось під час ірландської Земельної Війни у 1880 році від прізвища земельного агента одного з лордів, з яким відмовились працювати винаймачі землі через жорстке ставлення до них, через що йому довелось винайняти робітників з далеку, що обернулось великими витратами. Того ж року "Таймс" використало це слово в його сьогоднішньому значенні.

Чи є подібні приклади в українській мові? Які?

Comment: слова які походять від прізвищ, дуже розповсюджені, особливо для назви послідовників якоїсь ідеї, тому хотілось би дізнатись, чи саме прізвище (тут `тітушки` та `бандери` досить унікальні), чи похідні від них (`кравчучки`, `петлюрівці`, `мічурінці`, `гусити`, `якобіти` та `лєнінци`).

Comment: Я б обмежив такі слова по-перше - фаміліями українського походження, по-друге - тими, що продовжують вживатися в оригінальній форми, тобто є "фамілією групи людей" (як хулігани - члени сім'ї Hooligan) і не стали торговельною маркою.

Comment: Власне, українська мова доволі щедра на утворення загальних назв від власних — на відміну від англійської, де Nietzscheism, Aristotelian logic, Epicureanism продовжують писатися з великої літери (тобто вважаються власними назвами), в нас усі прикметники та -їзми від імен — це вже загальні назви: ніцшеанство, аристотелівська логіка, епікуреїзм. Тому Artemix правий, що варто обмежити до слів, що, власне, зберегли форму імені (а не всілякі -їзми, -їсти тощо).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Я б обмежив такі слова по-перше - фаміліями українського походження, по-друге - тими, що продовжують вживатися в оригінальній форми, тобто є "фамілією групи людей" (як хулігани - члени сім'ї Hooligan) і не стали торговельною маркою*.

Нещодавно з'явилося означення спортивних молодиків які на замовлення виконують агресивні дії:

#### Тітушки

> [Термін з'явився](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%96%D1%82%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8) у травні 2013 року і походить від прізвища спортсмена Вадима Тітушка.
>
> «Тіту́шки» — збірна назва найманців, часто люмпенізованих кримінальних елементів, гопників, молодиків, у тому числі спортсменів, які використовувалися українською владою для застосування фізичної сили і участі в масових сутичках; зокрема, для перешкоджання діяльності опозиційних активістів та для дій проти вуличних протестів: провокацій, підпалів машин, залякування, побиття та розгону демонстрацій, впливу на процес голосування на виборах тощо.

#### Бандери

Ще, може не зовсім у українській мові, - "**бандера**" може означати будь-якого українця (з точки зору деяких росіян), або, більш конкретно - національно свідомого українця. Ну і звісно що прообраз - [Степан Бандера](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).

**Кравчучка**, яку пригадав Chizh також має "фамільні риси" - вона створена як "Сердючка", "Бойчучка" і т.і. і означає "дружина або незаміжня донька чоловіка на прізвище Кравчук".

---

***Назви правописів царської доби** - вже не мають ознак "фамільності", залишу тут через їх лінгвістичність:
максимовичівка, кулішівка, драгоманівка, желехівка, грінченківка/грінчевичівка, [скрипниківка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81) (див. статтю [Правопис](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81) у Вікіпедії).*

*(Ще напевно є назви населених пунктів та сортів рослин (яблук), що формально є "словами утворенними від прізвищ" але напевно цей список буде майже нескінченним)*.

Comment: `Азірівка` ще є з нещодавнього

Comment: Так, але воно не вийшло за межі жартів, наскільки мені відомо.

Comment: Але були правописи - максимовичівка, кулішівка, драгоманівка, желехівка, грінченківка/грінчевичівка. https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81

Comment: Ще різні «ізми» – сталінізм, ленінізм, марксизм, а також «овщини» – махновщина, петлюровщина, лисенковщина. Також назви житлових будинків – сталінка, хрущовка.

Answer (score 11):

Невеличке інтернет-дослідження привело мене до [наступної статті](http://gazeta.ua/articles/istoriya-movi/_zvidki-vzyalisya-slova-rover-i-trempel/434288). В ній говориться про два *незвичних* діалектних слова.

1. Тремпель, яке частіше вживають на сході країни
2. Ровер, яке більш розповсюджене на заході

Зокрема в статті за посиланням зауважується, що

> **Rover** - так називалося британське підприємство, засноване 1887 року Джоном Кемпом Старлі й Вільямом Саттоном. ... Фірма Rover починала бізнес із випуску велосипедів. Перший з'явився 1884-го ... Доти велосипеди мали величезне переднє колесо з педалями й маленьке заднє. Фірма Rover їх "зрівняла" - зробила однакові за розміром. Їздити на такому велосипеді стало значно безпечніше й зручніше. Тож під кінець XIX ст. на "ровери" масово сіли діти й жінки по всій Європі. *Відтоді у Галичині, Буковині та на Закарпатті, що до 1918-го входили до Австро-Угорської імперії, ровером називають будь-який велосипед. А в польській і білоруській це слово стало літературним - rower і "ровар" відповідно.*

щодо тремпеля наводятся наступні відомості:

> Історія слова почалася з кравця на прізвище **Тремпель**. Нібито десь на зламі XIX-XX ст. у Харкові на вул. Плеханівській він заклав майстерню з пошиття верхнього одягу. Щоб вирізнитися серед конкурентів, продавав плащі, піджаки та шуби разом із вішаками. І ставив на ньому "фірмовий знак" - своє прізвище. ... *в жодному музеї нема експонатів-тремпелів зі згаданим логотипом. Тож історія із кравцем Тремпелем може бути легендою.* ... у німецькій було слово Тrempel або Drempel - допоміжна опора в будинку - додаткова стіна між верхнім поверхом і дахом

Також у статті наводяться мапи розповсюдження діалектизмів<sup>*</sup>:

Ровера:

[image: Використання слова ровер для позначення велосипеду, з якої видно, що найчастіше слово вживається на заході країни]

А також тремпеля:

[image: Використання слова тремпель для позначення вішака, з якої видно, що слово найчастіше використовується на сході та на сході центральної частини країни]

Можна сказати,

1. достеменно відомо, що слово `ровер` пішло від власної назви підприємства. що, я вважаю, достатньо близько до теми запитання.
2. у суспільній свідомості закріпилася версія: слово `тремпель` пішло від прізвища комерсанта. Історія про це слово могла би бути повноцінною відповіддю, але, на жаль, ця гіпотеза не підтверджується історичними дослідженнями.

<sup>*</sup>В статті вказано джерело мап: http://dialectstat.wikispaces.com/

Answer (score 11):

Не варто забувати про [`кравчучку`](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0):

> Кравчу́чка — доволі розповсюджена в Україні жаргонно-жартівлива назва візка для ручного перевезення вантажів, зробленого у вигляді L-подібної металевої рами з двома колесами (у всіх інших країнах — ручний візок).
>
> Кравчучка — ручний візок, відрізняється від інших засобів перевезення (возики, сумки, валізи) компактністю та простотою виготовлення. Вона мало важить, її можна скласти та перевозити у невеликому пакеті. Крім того, цей візок витримує навантаження до 100 кілограмів.
>
> Кравчучки набули особливого поширення в Україні на початку дев'яностих років XX століття. Особливо часто використовувалися роздрібними торговцями (човниками) та дачниками.
>
> Назва походить від прізвища тогочасного [Президента України Леоніда Кравчука](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D1%83%D0%BA_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B4_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), в період правління якого такий промисел з таким знаряддям набув масового характеру.

Comment: Гм, ще є Хрущов тоді. Набирається, одначе.

Comment: ну то неспецифічне, загально-совкове

Comment: В 90-х ще були спроби просунути мем "кучмовіз", як назву кравчучки-на-колесиках.

Answer (score 3):

Натрапив ще ось на такий словотвір, щоправда, вже успішно забутий: *пинзеник*.

У часописі ["Перець"](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C_(%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81)) №15 за 1993 рік читаємо:

> А мій милий захворів —
>
> Вареників захотів.
>
> — Купи, люба, масла й сиру,
>
> навари вареників!
>
> — Я б тобі купила, милий,
>
> та нема пинзеників.

[image: Знімок із журнала "Перець"]

Мається на увазі [купонокарбованець](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C#%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8_1992%E2%80%931996) 1992-96 років, який здешевлювався астрономічними темпами, що не могло не стати приводом для жартів. [Віктор Пинзеник](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) був міністром фінансів у 1992-93 роках.